# Setup to be somewhat anonymous

Tags: anonymity

Would I be "somewhat anonymous" if I purchased bitcoin using my real bank account, used that bitcoin to purchase a VPN-service that I can trust does not keep any logs, and use that VPN-service through TOR?

I may want to write about somewhat controversial subjects on the internet and watch some copyrighted streams of TV-shows. So by "somewhat anonymous" I don't mean the most hardcore security agencies, but private people, enforcers of copyright law etc.

Anything I should think about, anything I've gotten wrong? Tips?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. Can you narrow down your question a little?

Comment: Awesome and interesting topic for a long blog post, but by far to broad for SE. And yep, you [have that VPN thing wrong](https://www.whonix.org/w/index.php?title=Tunnels/Introduction&redirect=no#Connecting_to_Tor_before_a_tunnel-link_.28proxy.2FVPN.2FSSH.29).

Comment: @Sebb There's quite a lot of blog-length answers on this site that are incredible, so I don't think that really applies.

Comment: @SourLolita Yep, there are awesome long answer here and I do like them. However, there are so many possibilities and things to look out for that a good writeup which includes at least most most of the traps will take several pages - a lot longer than all answers I have seen.

Comment: @Sebb Ah, I see your point now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the transactions with bitcoins are publicly logged so anyone can see the bitcoin transaction.

There is a page from bitcoin wiki on how to keep your bitcoin anonymous titled [Bitcoin Wiki - Anonymity](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Anonymity). There is a section "Staying Anonymous", that will explain you how to transfer the coins between many accounts from different  eWallet providers.

So to your first question

> Would I be "somewhat anonymous" if I purchased bitcoin using my real bank account, used that bitcoin to purchase a VPN-service that I can trust does not keep any logs, and use that VPN-service through TOR?

Its no, first of all buy the bitcoin with cash and in small quotes and you still need to transfer your coins through several wallets - instead of tor use [tails](https://tails.boum.org/) , its a whole amnesic and anonymity distro instead of just a anonymity browser. Use proxychains and a vpn as well to create the ewallets and transactions.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy bitcoins with your real name attached to them, you wont be anonymous. Bitcoin is not anonymous by itself (http://www.bitcoinisnotanonymous.com/), and using it with your real name makes thinks only worse from the anonymity perspective.

Also I would not trust any vpn provider. But I if you really want you have it backward. Run tor through the VPN, not the other way around. At worst, vpn privider will monitor your encrypted tor traffic only.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin keeps an active ledger. When you buy btc with a bank account via a provider like coinbase they log that transaction and transfer bitcoins to your address then you buy vpn service with the bitcoins and the bitcoin ledger logs the transaction. I would use a service like LocalBitcoins to trade gift cards or cash for btc...that is more anonymous